# Why my code is duplicating the last 2 characters when I run it and I try to delete?

Tags: java, android, text, character

The main goal is to make each character different color when typed in app. This is Edit Text View that im using. This works but when I try to delete a character or characters it just duplicates last two chars ?!?! Im using Android Studio Bumblebee. Any help would be much appreciated ! Here is the code:

```
nameField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
 
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
 
    }
 
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
 
        if (s.length() > 0) {
            nameField.removeTextChangedListener(this);
 
            int start = s.length() - 1;
            String lastChar = s.toString().substring(start);
 
            SpannableString lastSpannableChar = new SpannableString(lastChar);
 
            int pickedColor = chooseColor(lastChar);
 
            ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(pickedColor);
 
            lastSpannableChar.setSpan(fcs, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
 
            ssb.append(lastSpannableChar);
 
            nameField.setText(ssb);
            nameField.setSelection(nameField.getText().length());
            nameField.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }
    }
});

public int chooseColor(String ch) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    return Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to paste the method Im using for generating the different colors. https://pastebin.com/LT5difPg

Comment: What is `ssb` ? You're adding the last characters to it...

Comment: ssb is the name of the variable of type SpannableStringBuilder... are you suggesting no to add it ?

Comment: It's a guess : you're adding 2 characters to it but do you remove some ?

Comment: @Bruno I kept trying to modify the code but nothing is going on... can you give me some more hints